# Obtener Respuesta Personalizada de Metodo Get c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, c#-8.0

Buen dia. Actualmente estoy desarrollando una web api en .net core 3.2, cuando hago la peticion a  GetBuildingsByApartments Obtengo el resultado de la peticion pero tambien me trae informacion acerca de sistema que no es importante para mi. Solo quiero obtener la clave *result* que se encuentra en la ultima parte, si alguien pudiera ayudarme le agradeceria:

Anexo la respuesta que obtengo cuando hago la peticion:

```
"codigo": 200,
"status": "success",
"objeto": {
    "stateMachine": {
        "<>1__state": 0,
        "<>t__builder": {},
        "<>4__this": {}
    },
    "context": {},
    "moveNextAction": {
        },
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Edificio el patio",
            "address": "calle 3 numero 17 - 45",
            "phone": "8354231",
            "country": "Colombia",
            "state": "Cauca",
            "city": "Popayan",
            "apartments": [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "number_apartment": "201",
                    "phone": "965656",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "number_apartment": "202",
                    "phone": "7654376",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "number_apartment": "203",
                    "phone": "7654376",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "number_apartment": "204",
                    "phone": "876548765",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 16,
                    "number_apartment": "205",
                    "phone": "76548765",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 17,
                    "number_apartment": "206",
                    "phone": "8765476",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "number_apartment": "207",
                    "phone": "8765487",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "number_apartment": "208",
                    "phone": "876576",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Edificio el quintas de san pedro",
            "address": "calle 3 numero 34 - 5",
            "phone": "566543",
            "country": "Colombia",
            "state": "Cauca",
            "city": "Cali",
            "apartments": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "number_apartment": "204",
                    "phone": "876548765",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "number_apartment": "208",
                    "phone": "876576",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "number_apartment": "207",
                    "phone": "8765487",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "number_apartment": "206",
                    "phone": "8765476",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "number_apartment": "205",
                    "phone": "76548765",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "number_apartment": "201",
                    "phone": "965656",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 21,
                    "number_apartment": "202",
                    "phone": "7654376",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 2
                },
                {
                    "id": 22,
                    "number_apartment": "203",
                    "phone": "7654376",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Edificio san lorenzo",
            "address": "calle 58 numero 23 - 45",
            "phone": "8354231",
            "country": "Colombia",
            "state": "Cauca",
            "city": "Popayan",
            "apartments": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "number_apartment": "206",
                    "phone": "8765476",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "number_apartment": "205",
                    "phone": "76548765",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "number_apartment": "204",
                    "phone": "876548765",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "number_apartment": "203",
                    "phone": "7654376",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "number_apartment": "202",
                    "phone": "7654376",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "number_apartment": "201",
                    "phone": "965656",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 23,
                    "number_apartment": "207",
                    "phone": "8765487",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 24,
                    "number_apartment": "208",
                    "phone": "876576",
                    "number_block": "c",
                    "buildingId": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Edificio miraflores",
            "address": "calle 3 numero 56 - 11",
            "phone": "7654344",
            "country": "Colombia",
            "state": "Cauca",
            "city": "Piendamo",
            "apartments": []
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Edificio editado popayan",
            "address": "calle 3 numero 17 - 45",
            "phone": "8354231",
            "country": "Colombia",
            "state": "Cauca",
            "city": "Popayan",
            "apartments": []
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Edificio editado popayan",
            "address": "calle 3 numero 17 - 45",
            "phone": "8354231",
            "country": "Colombia",
            "state": "Cauca",
            "city": "Popayan",
            "apartments": []
        }
    ],
    "id": 108,
    "exception": null,
    "status": 5,
    "isCanceled": false,
    "isCompleted": true,
    "isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
    "creationOptions": 0,
    "asyncState": null,
    "isFaulted": false
}
```

Utilizo patron Repository.

**BuildingHomeController.cs**

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("ByAparments")]
    public IActionResult GetBuildingsByApartments()
    {

        var result = this.buildingRepository.GetBuildingApartmentAsync();

        var returnObject = new
        {
            codigo = 200,
            status = "success",
            objeto = result
        };
        return Ok(returnObject);
    }
```

**BuildingRepository.cs**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BuildingHome>> GetBuildingApartmentAsync()
    {           
        var result = await context.Building.Include(b => b.Apartments).ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

**IBuildingRepository.cs**

```
public interface IBuildingRepository : IRepositoryBase<BuildingHome>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<BuildingHome>> GetBuildingApartmentAsync();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto que te está devolviendo es una `Task<BuildingHome>`. Para obtener el `BuildingHome` (el resultado de la `Task`), debes "awaitear" la misma.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ByAparments")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBuildingsByApartments()
{
    var result = await this.buildingRepository.GetBuildingApartmentAsync();
    var returnObject = new
    {
        codigo = 200,
        status = "success",
        objeto = result
    };

    return Ok(returnObject);
}
```

Y, por supuesto, deberás hacer el método `GetBuildingsByApartments` del *controller* `async`. Ahora devolverá una `Task<IActionResult>`, claro.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, funciono para mi..